# How can I put in quit?

Tags: pygame-surface

Can't exit even when I put in pygame.quit
I dont know how to make it work, can someone help me?

```
 

run = True

 
while run: 
    pygame.time.delay(13) 
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed() 
pygame.quit()
```

I tried to put in quit, and everything, but couldn't get it working
What are the solutions that can help me do it right?